# Using StringTemplate together with forms in SpringMVC

Tags: java, spring-mvc, stringtemplate

does anyone know how to use StringTemplate with forms in SpringMVC framework?

Any tips, tutorials...?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

here is one:

- http://ca.rroll.net/2009/06/18/using-stringtemplate-as-the-view-engine-for-your-spring-mvc-application/